Printing list and tuple elements combined with unpacking operator
I have a following code with different outputs
def func1(*args):
    print(type(args))
    print('Func1')
    for k in args:
        print (k)

def func2(args):
    print(type(args))
    print('Func2')
    for k in args:
        print (k)

func1([1,2,3])
func2([1,2,3])

while I generally know what unpacking operator does, I'm not sure why prints are so different.
The output is the following:
<class 'tuple'>
Func1
[1, 2, 3]
<class 'list'>
Func2
1
2
3

So, if in func1 arguments are unpacked and put into a tuple, I would expect that each print call put end of line, instead it behaves exactly as list is printed with square brackets.

*args packs all passed arguments into a tuple. You can pass multiple arguments to the function when calling it, and they'll all end up in args as a tuple. That's what * does for parameters.

just print args: ([1,2,3],) it's a one-tuple containing just a list

Yes, I understand now, especially with an example from @folen gateis. Basically, my list is a first (and only) element in a tuple. That is why it is printed like this.
